# Please explain this algorithm to get all permutations of a String

Tags: ansible, python, string, recursion, permutation

The following code generates all the permutations for a string:

```
def permutations(word):
    if len(word)<=1:
        return [word]

    #get all permutations of length N-1
    perms=permutations(word[1:])
    char=word[0]
    result=[]
    #iterate over all permutations of length N-1
    for perm in perms:
        #insert the character into every possible location
        for i in range(len(perm)+1):
            result.append(perm[:i] + char + perm[i:])
    return result
```

Can you explain how it works? I don't understand the recursion.

Comment: It looks like you have an indentation error here, also, it's worth pointing out that this code is re-inventing the wheel.  There's already `itertools.permutations` in the standard library :-) -- Though that doesn't help you understand this code.

Comment: What do you mean by "he" and "this man"?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I think that was just a "cute" way of asking what was going on in the code. I've rewritten the question to ask directly for an explanation, which I think was what the questioner wanted (and has received).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The algorithm is:

- Remove the first letter
- Find all the permutations of the remaining letters (recursive step)
- Reinsert the letter that was removed in every possible location.

The base case for the recursion is a single letter. There is only one way to permute a single letter.

**Worked example**

Imagine the start word is `bar`.

- First remove the `b`.
- Find the permuatations of `ar`. This gives `ar` and `ra`.
- For each of those words, put the `b` in every location:

  - `ar` -> `bar`, `abr`, `arb`
  - `ra` -> `bra`, `rba`, `rab`

Answer (score 7):

I've written the steps out for a string of length 2 and a string of length 3 below.

**permutations('ab')**

```
len('ab') is not <= 1 
perms = permutations of 'b'
len('b') <= 1 so return 'b' in a list
perms = ['b']
char = 'a'
result = []
for 'b' in ['b']:
    for 0 in [0,1]:
        result.append('' + 'a' + 'b')
    for 1 in [0,1]:
        result.append('b' + 'a' + '')
result = ['ab', 'ba']
```

**permutations('abc')**

```
len('abc') is not <= 1
perms = permutations('bc')
perms = ['bc','cb']
char = 'a'
result =[]
for 'bc' in ['bc','cb']:
    for 0 in [0,1,2]:
        result.append('' + 'a' + 'bc')
    for 1 in [0,1,2]:
        result.append('b' + 'a' + 'c')
    for 2 in [0,1,2]:
        result.append('bc' + 'a' + '') 
for 'cb' in ['bc','cb']:
    for 0 in [0,1,2]:
        result.append('' + 'a' + 'cb')   
    for 1 in [0,1,2]:
        result.append('c' + 'a' + 'b')   
    for 2 in [0,1,2]:
        result.append('cb' + 'a' + '')
result = ['abc', 'bac', 'bca', 'acb', 'cab', 'cba']
```